# What a peculiar animal

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

One day, as I was wandering in the forest, I came across a most peculiar animal. It came right in front of me and said to me:

> I watch
>   I salute
>   I am multiple
>   I am myself
>   I sting
>   I dig
>   I am yourself
>   I was
>   I question

What was this animal and could I milk it ?

Hint:

> It's a little bit more complicated than just finding an animal with these requirements.

Comment: Animals that salute? Well google had nothing :)

Comment: Can you milk a *titmouse?*

Comment: @Chowzen Damn, I was hoping that it'd be a big breasted mouse instead of a bird.

Comment: Disappointed for no "I protecc I attacc I get myself bacc on tracc"

Comment: Well, it said something, I bet it was either another human or parrot.

Comment: Should this be tagged [tag:lateral-thinking], based on the OP’s comments to various answers below regarding the literal meaning of the riddle?

Comment: @DonielF indeed, I added it

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is based on [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/u/9860/)'s idea and [J. Siebeneichler](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/u/30358/) and [Bass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/u/36023/)'s comments; I only contributed

> one letter

but since the answer hasn't been posted yet let's put it up!

> ... As M Oehm thought, each line corresponds to a letter (most of this is quoted from their answer):
>
>  • I watch — **C**: I *see*
>  • I salute —  **A**: as in, "hey!", or "ay!" (J.Siebeneichler suggestion)
>  • I am multiple — **R**: "I am" multiple is "we *are*"
>  • I am myself — **I**: literally *I*
>  • I sting — **B**: a *bee* stings
>  • I dig — **O**: <s>a circular hole, or I dig=I love=>love in tennis=0 => O (Bass suggestion)</s> a hoe!
>  • I am yourself: **U**: *you* yourself
>  • I was: — **X**: it is an ex-parrot, it was but is no more
>  • I question: **Y**: the question is *why*

It is indeed

> a Caribou, of the male persuasion,

and thus

> cannot be milked.

Unless you join [J. Siebeneichler](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/u/30358/)'s mind in the gutter of course! And who didn't.

Comment: Good job, team! Since @M Oehm is such a gentlemant, I'll accept this answer. Only one thing : I was more thinking of a tool for the "O"

Comment: Oh, a hoe! :) no?

Comment: @Keelhaul This is a really cool riddle by the way!

Comment: A really neat riddle - and nice teamwork on the answer!

Answer (score 28):

This is perhaps more of an idea than a real answer.

I think what's going on here is ...

> ... that each line represents a word that is a homophone of a letter. For example:
>
>  • I watch — **I** or **C**: An *eye* watches; I *see*
>  • I salute —  ?
>  • I am multiple — **R**: "I am" multiple is "we *are*"
>  • I am myself — **I** or **M**: literally *I* or *am*
>  • I sting — **B**: a *bee* stings
>  • I dig — ?
>  • I am yourself: **U**: *you* yourself
>  • I was: — ?
>  • I question: **Y**: the question is *why*
>
>  When I squint, I can see a caribou hidden in these lines, but I can't really make it stick. (I also half-expect the animal to be one for which there is a famous question along the lines of "Can you milk a ___?")

Comment: Robert DeNiro asked Ben Stiller in *Meet the Parents* if Ben could milk *him*...

Comment: I salute could be "hey" for A.

Comment: Possibly you could dig a circular hole

Comment: @Bass: Either that or "I dig" means "I love" and in tennis love means zero and a zero looks like the letter O. How's that for lateral thinking`?

Comment: `i salute` could be `Hi` i.e `i`

Comment: OK, I found it but feel bad putting it in an answer because it's based on this answer and its comments; I think M Oehm should update. J.Siebeneichler & Bass have it right, also "I was" is "ex" and you cannot milk the animal!

Comment: @RozennKeribin don't feel bad, it's common here to post the answer after being helped by the comments. You can credit the people who helped you in your post though ;)

Comment: XY is the male chromosome, so I guess you can't milk it (unless you consider its "special milk" :-P )

Comment: I also found it @RozennKeribin , but I will let you post it :)

Comment: @RozennKeribin: No need to feel bad. My answer was really just "thinking aloud". And congratulations! I would never have solved that.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a little bit of a stretch, but you are a:

> Bee

I watch

> Bee always watching?

I salute

> Something related to the Queen Bee or [GRAMMYs to salute Bee Gees](https://www.grammy.com/.../news/demi-lovato-pentatonix-salute-bee-gees-cbs-special)

I am multiple

> Beehive

I am myself

> Related to the verb "to be", To Be Myself?

I sting

> Bee sting

I dig

> Some type of bees dig

I am yourself

> Related to the verb "to be", Be Yourself?

I was

> Past of the verb to be?

I question

> This I don't know

Could you milk it?

> A metaphor for the honey? Or [Royal Jelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_jelly) which is considered Bee Milk

Comment: Don't get too attached to the literal sense of this riddle, it's not an ant and it's not a bee either :)

Comment: I guess it's not right, but I liked this idea.  Also, for "I question" - to be or not to be - would fit.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's probably

> an ant.

*I watch*
*I salute*

> Soldier ants.

*I am multiple*
*I am myself*

> Like some other insects, ants have a sort of 'hive mind': the anthill community functions almost as a single organism. It's thought that ants don't have much individuality.

*I sting*
*I dig*

> Some ants have stinging bites. Others dig holes in the ground.

*I am yourself*
*I was*
*I question*

> Not sure about these lines.

Comment: You wish it was that easy... but it's not :D

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> A pond / river reflection of yourself ?

Because

> The all points are applicable to you ?

Comment: A pond/river is not an animal

Comment: Yes, i meant yourself, the human animal(Humans are animals i have read somewhere)  :P

Comment: Still not it ^^

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Koala(Koala bear)

I watch
  I salute

> Koalas sometime salute

I am multiple
I am myself

> Koala is a marsupial, carrying its young one on itself

I sting
I dig

> It attacks with nails, and digs the ground for food

I am yourself

> Koalas sleep for about 20 hours a day :p

I was
I question

> No idea

And yes it is possible to milk this animal.

Comment: Again, don't get too attached to the literal sense of this riddle. Not a koala.